# Queries to XML, Notice: Array to string conversion in

Tags: php, xml

i want to convert my mysql queries to **XML** and for that i've used the code of this tutorial : http://www.codediesel.com/php/converting-mysql-queries-to-xml/ i had to customize it to use **PDO** instead of **mysql** functions.
here's the code :

```
function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{ 
    $xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";

    while($record = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    { 
        /* Create the first child element  */
        $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $queryResult->columnCount(); $i++)
        { 
            $fieldName = $queryResult->getColumnMeta($i);

            /* The child will take the name of the table column  */
            $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";

            /* We set empty columns with NULL, or you could set 
                it to '0' or a blank. */
            if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
                $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
            else
                $xmlData .= "null"; 

            $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
        } 
        $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 

    return $xmlData; 
}
```

But when i try to execute the code i get this error : 
Notice: Array to string conversion in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/promos/t.php** on line **42**

Notice: Array to string conversion in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/promos/t.php** on line **42**

Notice: Array to string conversion in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/promos/t.php** on line **42**

Notice: Array to string conversion in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/promos/t.php** on line **42**
nullnullnullnull

the line **42** is :

```
if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
```

Do you have any idea about this ? Thank you :)

Comment: You can't treat array as an string!

Comment: try `$fieldName = $queryResult->getColumnMeta()[$i];`

Comment: @Jarry thank you :) it gives me : `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in`

Comment: my bad, you cant use [] before a function. it has to be done in two sentences. see my answer, for a better solution(i think).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the function getColumnMeta returns an array. not a string.
besides that, its marked as experimental. i wouldnt use it on a production code until it becames more stable.

but i think this should work

```
function sqlToXml($queryResult, $rootElementName, $childElementName)
{ 
    $xmlData = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-1\" ?>\n"; 
    $xmlData .= "<" . $rootElementName . ">";


    while($record = $queryResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
    { 
        /* Create the first child element  */
        $xmlData .= "<" . $childElementName . ">";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $queryResult->columnCount(); $i++)
        { 
            $colum = $queryResult->getColumnMeta($i);
            $fieldName = $column['name'];

            /* The child will take the name of the table column  */
            $xmlData .= "<" . $fieldName . ">";

            /* We set empty columns with NULL, or you could set 
                it to '0' or a blank. */
            if(!empty($record->$fieldName))
                $xmlData .= $record->$fieldName; 
            else
                $xmlData .= "null"; 

            $xmlData .= "</" . $fieldName . ">"; 
        } 
        $xmlData .= "</" . $childElementName . ">"; 
    } 
    $xmlData .= "</" . $rootElementName . ">"; 

    return $xmlData; 
}
```

Comment: thank you. it sayes that getCloumnMeta() needs an argument, so it gives me this error : `Warning: PDOStatement::getColumnMeta() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in`

Answer (score 0):

You want the fieldname, so you have to retrieve it from the associative array returned by [getColumnMeta()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php) where you wrongly thought it returned a string, so just replace your following line:

```
$fieldName = $queryResult->getColumnMeta($i);
```

for this one:

```
$fieldName = $queryResult->getColumnMeta($i);
$fieldName = $fieldName['name'];
```

that should make `$fieldName` to contain the field name and so the rest of your code will work.

Comment: Thank you :) it shows me the result but i don't know why it doesn't give it to me in xml format (surrouded with <> )